# Horizontal tableView orientation changes

Tags: ios, tableview, device-orientation

I'm creating UITableView which is horizontal using this lines:

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);

cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```

What I'm trying to do is set centered on the screen with full screen width.
After initialization everything seems fine but when I rotate device I"m loosing control;/

Here are methods which I use to initialize:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageDownloadsInProgress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width)];

    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5);
    self.tableView.center = self.view.center;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 200.0f;
}
```

and rotation handler where everything goes wrong:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
       fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width)];
        self.tableView.center = self.view.center;
    } else {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 200);
        self.tableView.center = self.view.center;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Im thinking maybe on some resizing masks to keep it in vertical center and horizontal stretched?